# how to add binary attachment in ebay tradin api UploadSiteHostedPictures request

Tags: ebay-api

Can anyone genius show me JSON example of UploadSiteHostedPictures request with binary attachment.
Help please. Cant find this solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The binary is not in the request body but it must be sent as a MIME attachment, in your POST request.